# Transición para que se deslice hacia abajo y arriba un Nav

Tags: javascript, css, html5, responsive

Tengo un menú responsive, todo funciona muy bien, pero quisiera saber como hacer que cuando uno apriete el botón para que se abra el menú, que el `ul` se deslice suavemente hacia abajo y que no aparezca de repente. Es medio feo ver que aparezca de la nada.
Les comparto mi HTML

```
<nav id="myTopNav" class="topNav responsive">
            <ul id="menuBlock">
                <li><a href="../index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="rubros.html">Rubros</a></li>
                <li><a href="nuestra-empresa.html">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a href="area-clientes.html">Clientes</a>

                <li><a href="busqueda-productos.html">Búsqueda</a>
                </li>

                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
```

Mi CSS es este:

```
nav a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 19px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 5px;

    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;

    position: relative;
}

nav li:hover {

    color: #BADA55;
}

/* Responsive */
@media (min-width:100px) and (max-width:1200px) {
    header {
        display: inline;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .topNav.responsive {
        display: none;
        

    }

    .topNav ul {
        background-color: #BADA55;
        border: 6px #5F634F solid;
        width: 100%;
        transition: 0.3 ease;
        
    }

    .topNav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        
        
    }
    .topNav ul li a{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
       
    }
   .topNav.responsive ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        left: 10px;
        background-color: #5F634F;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Y mi JS (Javascript) es este:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopNav");
    if (x.className === "topNav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topNav";
      x.slideToggle(); 
    }
  }
```

Funciona bastante bien, pero lo que me falta es hacer esa suave transición. Probé con `transition: all 1s ease`, pero no funcionó.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Las transiciones en CSS no funcionan con la propiedad `display`. En su lugar, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. En la hoja de estilos, asigna la propiedad de transición a las opciones del menú.
2. Crea una clase que establezca las propiedades `height` y `width` en cero y asígnala a las opciones del menú en el código HTML (no al botón que se pulsará y mostrará/ocultará las opciones del menú).
3. En el código JS, asocia una función al menú que se ejecute con cada clic/pulsación.
4. En cada ejecución de esa función, verifica si las opciones del menú poseen la clase que las oculta. De ser así, retírala y automáticamente recobrarán sus dimensiones originales. Como previamente les asignaste la propiedad de transición, se mostrarán progresivamente. Y para ocultarlas, en la misma función verifica si no poseen dicha clase para que, en ese caso, se las vuelvas a asignar y así las opciones del menú se volverán a ocultar.

Un ejemplo:

```js
let menu = document.querySelector("#menu"),
    opciones = document.querySelectorAll("nav li:not(#menu)");

menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    [].forEach.call(opciones, (opcion) => {
        if (opcion.classList.contains("hide")){
            opcion.classList.remove("hide");
        }
        else{
            opcion.classList.add("hide");
        }
    });
}, false);
```

```css
nav{
    width: 20%;
}

nav li{
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #183683;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1%;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all ease .2s;
}

nav li:not(#menu):hover{
    filter: brightness(1.5);
}

#menu{
    background-color: #000;
}

.hide{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <li id="menu">Menú</li>
    <li class="hide">Opción 1</li>
    <li class="hide">Opción 2</li>
    <li class="hide">Opción 3</li>
</nav>
```

Puedes ajustar el tiempo de transición a tu gusto.

La otra opción es que emplees el método `.toggle()` de jQuery:

```
$("#menu").on("click", () => $("nav li:not(#menu)").toggle(200));
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. EL tema es que si le aplico la propiedad hide, se me rompe el menú...